# Check if all JS scripts on site are loaded properly

Tags: javascript, python, http

I've got couple of sites and couple of JS scripts inside them. I'm wondering if it is way to monitor that this javascript code load properly after site load **by python**...
Is there any way to check this using e.g selenium?
This is for icinga check. 
Many thanks for help!

Comment: Chrome->Developer Tools->Sources, all loaded JS scripts are listed there.

Comment: ... _by python_ ;)